# Android Switching between Viewpager produces Android crash

Tags: android, exception, arraylist, android-viewpager

I have five fragments in an View pager. One of them is a BarcodeFragment [BarcodeFragment](https://github.com/ikermendi/barcodefraglibv2_ikermendi) and I am getting a very weird android crash when I swipe between ViewPager fragments quickly. The crash Im getting is on the android side. This is the log.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:481)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeInactive(FragmentManager.java:1169)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1078)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1212)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:652)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I suspect its happening because of the following :
Whenever I am at the barcodeFragment and I want to switch to another fragment in the viewpager I remove the fragment using the following code:

```
if (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.barcode_Fragment) != null) {
                if (mBarcodeFragment != null && mBarcodeFragment.isResumed()) {
                    mBarcodeFragment.onDestroy();
                    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mBarcodeFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    mBarcodeFragment = null;
                }
            }
```

And whenever I am coming back to the BaseScanFragment (Which is the fragment which calls the Barcode Fragment) , I am adding the fragment again through the following code.:

```
mBarcodeFragment = new BarcodeFragment();
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.barcode_Fragment, mBarcodeFragment).commit();
    mBarcodeFragment.setDecodeFor(IScanResultHandler.MODE.SHOP_NOW_MODE);
    mBarcodeFragment.setScanResultHandler((IScanResultHandler) getSherlockActivity());
```

Can anyone guess what the problem is?

Comment: Why are you removing and adding back fragment this way? ViewPager is supposed to take care of managing fragments inside it. Also, do not call fragment lifecycle method onDestroy directly.

Comment: I have to do it as I am using the Barcode Fragment elsewhere as well. Barcode Fragment accesses Camera and there can only be one instance of the fragment at all times. So the problem is I have to remove it and then add it each time I am accessing the Scan thing.

Comment: Anyway calling mBarcodeFragment.onDestroy() in your code is not correct.

Comment: ive removed that...still the same thing

Comment: this is not related to your fragment and their transaction i think your logcat is not complete post it completely.

Comment: That is the problem. This is the only log I am getting.

Comment: have you solved this error???

Comment: yes, but I had to refactor the whole code I had written for removing the fragment. Trick is to do everything before super.onPaue() in onPause method.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem earlier when I was working with nested fragments. In my case it was occurring because I was using the wrong Fragment manager i.e I was accidentally using the Activity fragment manager for child fragment transactions

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7
```

The index points to the fragment in which this error is occurring i.e 7.