# Activity onStop() ==> Unable to stop activity {xxx}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5

Tags: android

this exception happened in activity's onstop, there are no myself code, all android framework code. i don't kown anything what happened!

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {xxx}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4380)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4447)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1562)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6459)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.setStoppedState(WindowManagerGlobal.java:597)
    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:6842)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4375)
    ... 9 more
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.setStoppedState(WindowManagerGlobal.java:597)
    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:6842)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4375)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4447)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1562)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6459)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
```

Comment: post code where ever you used array

Comment: post your onstop code

Comment: Are you [using fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26041795/1270789)?

Comment: not using fragment

Comment: this is my code in on stop: 
'
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mVideoView != null) {
            mVideoView.pause();
        }
    }
'
and mVideoView is PLVideoTextureView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your video view is running and then try to pause it.

Comment: it may be running.  so i call videoview.onpause to pause play!

Comment: Agreed. But you are checking only for the nullability of that particular view. You should also check whether something is getting rendered or not.  Try using `if (mVideoView != null && mVideoView .isRunning())`. Let me know what happens. Thanks. Have not used "PLVideoTextureView", so the isRunning part might be different.

Comment: i have added this code!   After a period of time, if it is usful, i will do it

Answer (score 0):

IndexOutOfBoundsException usually occurs when suppose you have only one element in your arraylist and you are trying to get arraylist.elementatindex[1] which gives IndexOutOfBoundsException because there's only one element in your arraylist.

Comment: i know that.   but this  exception occur in the android framework code